# Best way to save a sometimes store-generated column

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity that has one column with strange behavior.  On insert sometimes it is set to a value passed by the application and sometimes it uses the newly-created identity value from another column.  This is currently implemented using a stored procedure.  Is there a clean way to do this with Entity Framework?

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with Code First, but I'm not doing database generation or using migrations.

I know that I can essentially use a DbContext.Database to manually call a procedure as if I'm not using EF, but then I lose all of EF's automatic updates of the entity on save, participation in a SaveChanges transaction, etc.  What's the best way to mitigate this?

Edit:
I will try to describe my ideal solution in pseudo code.  The question is really how close can I get to this with real code given Entity Framework 6's current functionality.

Ideally I could just configure a column to sometimes be an "identity" column.  In other words, sometimes generated by the database on insert, sometimes not.  Something like this:

```
public sealed class WidgetConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Widget>
{
    public WidgetConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(d => d.Id);
        Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(e => e.Number)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.SometimesIdentity);
        MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Insert(i => i.HasName("InsertWidget")));
    }
}
```

Since this is not possible, I'm wondering if there is some other way of participating in SaveChanges so that I can take advantage of the EF goodness like dependency analysis and automatic transaction management rather than:

1. Creating a transaction
2. Populating a context with new/changed entities that a Widget depends on and saving it.
3. Inserting the Widget.
4. Populating a context with new/changed entities that depend on the Widget and saving it.
5. Committing the transaction.

In other words, is it possible to tell EF, "Hey, I know how to save Widgets.  Here's a callback when you need to save one." or something like that?

Comment: Please edit your question and include code to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

EF does not refresh the entities that may be affected by a StoredProcedure you have to do it manually by calling:

```
dbContext.Entry(myEntityToRefresh).Reload();
//or
dbContext.Entry(myEntityToRefresh).ReloadAsync();
```

Please change the title of this question. It says nothing.

Comment: I've changed the title, although I'm really struggling to phrase the question itself correctly, let alone summarize it in a title.

Comment: This is a good suggestion and gets me part of what I'd ideally like, but the downsides are an extra trip to the database and it's not participating in `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

Comment: SP are executed immediately, not when SaveContext is called. If you want to rollback you can use `TransactionScope`